# vba conversão de dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, macro

pessoal tenho uma macro que pega um arquivo dentro de uma pasta, converte ele de txt com largura fixa para csv e salva em uma outra pasta. eu recebo cerca de 400 a 450 arquivos neste formato para conversão, a macro ficou muito grande e dividi em 4 partes. até ai ok pq funciona bem, porém existe uma variação nos arquivos exemplo: mes passado eu recebi o arquivo djacy_txt e este mes eu nao recebi, então quando a macro chega no arquivo djacy_txt e nao encontra ele para me diz que houve um erro porque nao encontrou o arquivo.
gostaria de saber como eu faco para por um se (`if`) na macro p que ela faça assim:

se encontrar o arquivo XXXX.txt faça (macro de conversão)
senao procurar proximo arquivo.

```vb
<
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="P:\MACRO P CONVERSÃO\VBA\BRUTO\djacy.txt", _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(76, _
        1), Array(87, 1), Array(92, 1), Array(93, 1), Array(104, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(113, 1), _
        Array(125, 1), Array(145, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("Q5").Select
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    dirCopia = "P:\MACRO P CONVERSÃO\VBA\CONVERTIDO\"
    nomeCopia = "djacy"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
dirCopia + nomeCopia, _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
Workbooks("marcelo.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!
Sim, é possível inserir uma cláusula `if` para resolver esse caso.

Primeiramente, lendo essa parte do código que você postou, tive a impressão de que você criou um bloco de código para cada nome de arquivo a ser convertido. Para deixar o código mais rápido, eu criei uma estrutura de repetição `Do While...Loop` para abrir e salvar uma cópia do arquivo convertido, de acordo com o nome do arquivo.

Para essa estrutura funcionar, na minha planilha, eu fiz uma aba "Busca" da planilha com uma listinha com o nome de cada arquivo (eu usei os nomes fictícios A, B e C, os quais é só substituir pelo nome dos seus arquivos sem a extensão).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para tratar o erro de não encontrar o arquivo, eu inseri uma cláusula `if` que pula uma linha na planilha caso o erro 1004 (erro de Tempo de Execução, o qual ocorre quando um objeto não é identificado).

O código é esse abaixo. Você precisará substituir os caminhos dos arquivos de acordo com a maneira com que os arquivos originais estão salvos no seu PC e para qual pasta as cópias deverão ser salvas:

```
Private Sub btBusca_Click()

'Declara as variáveis
Dim W           As Worksheet
Dim Arquivo     As String
Dim dirArquivo  As String
Dim Copia       As String
Dim dirCopia    As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Atribui valores as variávies
Set W = Sheets("Busca") 'Aba Busca, em que está a lista de arquivos
dirArquivo = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Stack Overflow\Arquivos\" 'Caminho onde os arquivos .txt estão salvos
dirCopia = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Stack Overflow\Cópias\" 'Caminho onde os arquivos .csv deverão ser salvos

'Esvazia a variável Arquivo
Arquivo = Empty

'Seleciona a célula A2 na aba Busca
W.Range("A2").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Realiza a estrutura de repetição para abrir e converter cada arquivo .txt
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    Arquivo = ActiveCell.Value
    
    'No caso de erro, continua o código sem interrução
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Abre o arquivo .txt especificado
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=dirArquivo & Arquivo & ".txt"
    
    'No caso de erro 1004 (Tempo de Execução), pula uma linha na aba Busca e continua o código
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    Else
    
        'Converte e salva o arquivo no formato .csv
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dirCopia & Arquivo & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    End If
    
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Cópias criadas", vbOKOnly, "Processo Concluído!"

End Sub
```

A resposta ficou grande, mas o código é rápido e funciona.

Qualquer problema, me avise.

Comment: OBRIGADO! fiz um script em 5 partes para nomear cada arquivo, mais do jeito que voce montou o loop eu preciso somente de 1 modelo para cada layout!